# MySQL select that takes 2 values from a column and returns a single row

Tags: mysql

please could someone help me with this. I can't seems to get my mind around the SQL statement I need to get what I want. Below is my table.

```
| product_id  | product_name |  product_thumb_image  | 
------------------------------------------------------
|     1       |   ProductA   |  images/img_A.jpg    |
|     2       |   ProductB   |  images/img_B.jpg    |
|     3       |   ProductB   |  images/img_B2.jpg   |
|     4       |   ProductC   |  images/img_C.jpg    |
|     5       |   ProductD   |  images/img_D.jpg    |
```

Notice there are 2 ProductBs.

I would like a SQL statement to select the "product_thumb_image" such that it returns a row for each product name, but where a product has a 2nd image then a second column is also return.

e.g.

```
| mages/img_A.jpg  |  NULL/0/''          |
| mages/img_B.jpg  |  images/img_B2.jpg  |
| mages/img_C.jpg  |  NULL/0/''          |
| mages/img_D.jpg  |  NULL/0/''          |
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can a product have more than two images?

Comment: Yes it can, although it would not normally exceed 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is significantly easier to solve with ranking functions but MySQL does not support them yet. Instead, you can simulate a rank:

```
Select P.product_name
    , Min( Case When P.ProductRank = 0 Then product_thumb_image End ) As Image0
    , Min( Case When P.ProductRank = 1 Then product_thumb_image End ) As Image1
From    (
        Select product_id, product_name, product_thumb_image
            , (Select Count(*)
                From Products As P2
                Where P2.product_name = P1.product_name
                    And P2.product_id < P1.product_Id) As ProductRank
        From Products As P1
        ) As P
Group By P.product_name
```

Here's another way to write the same query which might perform better:

```
Select P.product_name
    , Min( Case When P.ProductRank = 0 Then product_thumb_image End ) As Image0
    , Min( Case When P.ProductRank = 1 Then product_thumb_image End ) As Image1
From    (
        Select P1.product_id, P1.product_name, P1.product_thumb_image
            , Count(P2.product_id) As ProductRank
        From Products As P1
            Left Join Products As P2
                On P2.product_name = P1.product_name
                    And P2.product_id < P1.product_Id
        Group By P1.product_id, P1.product_name, P1.product_thumb_image
        ) As P
Group By P.product_name
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas but when I run either SQL statement in phpMyAdmin nothing happens, I don't even get an error or get told that 0 rows were returned.

Comment: @Martin - Odd. Using your test data I did in fact get the results you wanted. Do you get results when run just the inner query by itself? In the first query, you are simply selecting directly from the products table so there shouldn't be any reason you do not get results. In the second solution, it left joins against itself so again, you should get something.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, both your SQL statements work well, albeit it is a bit long. They do answer the question I asked, +1 for you. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need two subselects. One to get the first image, one for the second:

```
SELECT t1.product_name, t2.product_thumb_image, t3.product_thumb_image
FROM mytable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT x.product_thumb_image
                 FROM mytable x
                 WHERE x.product_name = t1.product_name
                 LIMIT 0,1) t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT x.product_thumb_image
                 FROM mytable x
                 WHERE x.product_name = t1.product_name
                 LIMIT 1,1) t3
GROUP BY t1.product_name
```

Answer (score 1):

With a variable number of images per product, writing MySQL to return the columns you want is going to be difficult and rather clunky. Instead, why not run a simple [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to return a comma separated list, then split the results in your application.  As you are returning a list of filenames, the comma separator is unlikely to occur in the filename:

```
SELECT
  `product_name`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`product_thumb_image`) AS product_thumb_images
FROM `product`
GROUP BY `product_name`;

+--------------+------------------------------------+
| product_name | product_thumb_images               |
+--------------+------------------------------------+
| ProductA     | images/img_A.jpg                   |
| ProductB     | images/img_B.jpg,images/img_B2.jpg |
| ProductC     | images/img_C.jpg                   |
| ProductD     | images/img_C.jpg                   |
+--------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Mike fantastic solution! Thank you! Simple SQL statement that met my needs in another way.